# Is it okay to store articles in a MySQL database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, content-management-system

I want to store articles in a MySQL database, so I will just have 5 pages in HTML that would load necessary content from that database, but I don't know if that's a good idea. For example, would it lag after adding 1000 posts to that database? I am new to MySQL, and I just want to know if that's a good idea, and if not - what are good alternatives to that?

EDIT #1:
I forgot to mention - these articles won't be displayed all at once, they would be just stored in the database. The HTML file would show appropriate article from that database.

EDIT #2:
If storing each article in a database is bad, is it okay if I would store every article in a separate file, but at the same I would make a database which would store paths to these articles? I think that I would need such a database because it would make it easier to manage the content.

Comment: It'd be better to store articles in files.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if the files are generally larger than 100k, then better to store in file system. Size isn't the only criterion, but to say more would be too large for a comment, and too off topic for an answer.

Comment: There is no general yes or no answer to this question. It largely depends on the size of the content and the number of images / videos / other media content embedded into the content. You meed to do your own research.

Comment: I have done it and, as you've said, there is no general yes or no answer. The content on my website would be made by users, and there wouldn't be much videos, but there would be quite a lot of text and maybe some images.